# Can you take a new Lore skill on levelups?

Tags: skills, pathfinder-2e

When you level up and gain either a skill increase or increase your Intelligence modifier and can "become trained in an additional skill and language" (See [Leveling Up](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=116)), can you choose to gain a new Lore skill and become Trained in it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes

> Lore features many subcategories. You might have Military Lore, Sailing Lore, Vampire Lore, or any similar subcategory of the skill. **Each subcategory counts as its own skill**, so applying a skill increase to Planar Lore wouldn't increase your proficiency with Sailing Lore, for example.

As described under the rules for [Lore skills](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=8), each individual Lore is its own skill and would be eligible for a skill increase.